# Asp.net Client Certificate prevent browser "select a certificate" popping up from server side

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ssl-certificate

I have an set of ASP.NET Web APIs which support both client certificate and token based authentication.

In my code, I use OWIN for token based auth.
I also have a delegating handler for certificate based auth. 
In my WebRole.cs, I set sslFlags = "SslNegotiateCert"

I have a UI which consumes these APIs, UI always sends token to service so it uses token based Auth.  However, when we access the UI, a "select a certificate" window would pop up which I don't want.

Is there anything I can do at the Server side to prevent this?

Comment: I am curious what others will answer, but as far as I know, SSL negotiation has to happen *before* the token can be streamed to the server, so there is no way to turn it off conditionally based on the token or anything else in the payload for that matter.  The web server can't see the token until it is already too late. You might consider using a different endpoint (e.g. a subdomain or virtual directory) bound to the same web handler.

Comment: Hi John, when the server is set to "Accept Client Certificate", does it mean the browser will always pop up a "Select a Certificate" window?  Can we somehow tell the browser not to?

Comment: Probably not... check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619577/is-there-a-way-to-control-browsers-certificate-selection-popup-manually), which also suggests using two domains.